# Importing a dotted-name package locally for unit testing

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to develop and test a package foo.bar. I have the following directory layout:

```
myproject
  setup.py (for package foo.bar)
  foo
    bar
      __init__.py
      ...
  tests
    main.py
    test_something.py
```

In test_something.py, I want to import the local copy of foo.bar ideally just using 'import foo.bar'.

In main.py I have:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import test_something
```

However, I get an error:

```
File "./tests/main.py", line 22, in <module>
  import test_something
File "/myproject/tests/test_something.py", line 28, in <module>
  import foo.bar
ImportError: No module named bar
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `foo` to be considered as a package, you need to have a `__init__.py` directly under `foo` directory, it can be empty, but the file needs to be there. Otherwise Python would not consider `foo` as a package, and you cannot do -

```
import foo.bar
```

---

As said in the comments -

> In any event I don't want foo to be a package, I want foo.bar to be the package.

This is not directly possible, as in, you cannot do `import foo.bar` unless `foo` is a Python package (or a namespace package explained below).

The only other alternative here would be to add `foo` folder directly into `sys.path` using -

```
sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'foo')))
```

And then you would have to import it as -

```
import bar
```

---

If you are using **Python 3.3 +** , then you can use `namespace packages` , and you can import `foo.bar` without having to define a `__init__.py` inside `foo`.

This is explained well in - [PEP 0420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) , According to the specification, the new laoding procedure for python packages/modules (from 3.3 +) is -

> During import processing, the import machinery will continue to iterate over each directory in the parent path as it does in Python 3.2. While looking for a module or package named "foo", for each directory in the parent path:
>
> - If `<directory>/foo/__init__.py` is found, a regular package is imported and returned.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd}` is found, a module is imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by platform and whether the -O flag is specified. The list here is representative.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo` is found and is a directory, it is recorded and the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
> - Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
>
> If the scan completes without returning a module or package, and at least one directory was recorded, then a namespace package is created. The new namespace package:
>
> - Has a `__path__` attribute set to an iterable of the path strings that were found and recorded during the scan.
> - Does not have a `__file__` attribute.

Comment: I had tried that already, and it didn't work. In any event I don't want foo to be a package, I want foo.bar to be the package. Think of foo as the TLD name for a group of separately installable packages foo.package1, foo.package2, etc. And these are packages, not modules, as they should be separately installable (amongst other reasons because they have different transitive dependencies).

Comment: You cannot have both `foo.bar` be a package and `foo` not be a package, either both `foo` as well as `bar` are packages, or you import as `import bar` after adding `foo` folder to `sys.path` .

Comment: Hmm, Are you sure you had added `__init__.py`  with (two underscores) on both sides directly inside `foo` ? And that you are adding `myproject` folder into the `sys.path` ? If so, what does `print(sys.path)` give inside `test_something.py` just before trying to import `foo.bar` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure:

    touch foo/__init__.py

And notice the sys.path.append in the original question.

Comment: Where did you give that command? Inside `tests` or inside `myproject` ?

Comment: Just for testing, does doing this - `sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'foo')))` and then `import bar` work for you?

Comment: Mmm, okay, I have realized that there is an additional import in the real project that is causing at least part of the problem here (and is why I am getting 'no package bar' as opposed to 'no package foo.bar'). Thanks for your help; I need to dig into this more to get a better understanding of what is going on and perhaps report this more accurately.

Comment: Just FYI , I have updated the answer, with information about something called `namespace packages` , you can take a look if you are interested, that does not require `foo` to have ` __init__.py` .

Comment: Thanks, will do. On my end, the problem seems to be the fact that I have these multiple foo.bar1, foo.bar2 etc packages. If they are installed on the system there is no issue as they all end up under foo, but in source form where I want to run my tests there is more than one foo directory. Without an __init__.py under foo things fail as you suggested, and with __init__.py, only the first one works but any subsequent ones fail, presumably because Python importer thinks that all foo.* must live under that first foo.