# Difference between importing module in Python 3.4 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4

I am trying to import a package present in another folder and it is working perfectly fine in python 3.4. For Example: the files are present in libraries folder

```
user> python
Python 3.4.1 (default, Nov 12 2014, 13:34:29)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from libraries.controller_utils import *
>>>
```

However when I open a new shell and use Python 2.7:

```
user> python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Jun  1 2015, 10:35:58)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from libraries.controller_utils import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libraries.controller_utils
>>>
```

I tried adding the entry to `sys.path` but it is not helping. I read a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249119/difference-in-package-importing-between-python-2-7-and-3-4) but the solution is not helping me either as I tried both relative and absolute imports. Please advice.

EDIT: The directory structure being `~/tests/libraries/controller_utils.py`. I am executing these commands inside the tests directory.

EDIT: I have added the sys.path entry as follows but it still does not recognize it. Please note that the error occurs on 2.7 but works absolutely fine on 3.4

```
user> cd ~/tests/
user> ls
__pycache__  backups  inputs  libraries  openflow.py  test_flow.py
user> ls libraries/
__pycache__  controller_utils.py  general_utils.py  general_utils.pyc  tc_name_list.py  test_case_utils.py
user> python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Jun  1 2015, 10:35:58)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from libraries.controller_utils import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libraries.controller_utils
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('libraries/')
>>> from libraries.controller_utils import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libraries.controller_utils
```

Comment: What is the directory structure for the module you are importing? which directory are you running the python from?

Comment: What "entry" did you add to `sys.path` (and how did you add it?)?  Normally, with relative import problems, I'd expect you to find the module on python2.x and not on python3.x ...

Comment: The way in which you are modifying `sys.path` is wrong. if you add `libraries/` to `sys.path` then you should use `from controller_utils import *` not `from libraries.constroller_utils import *`.

Comment: You have to add `libraries/__init__.py`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `libraries` package is missing the `__init__.py` file. You can create an empty file with that name and then:

```
from libraries.controller_utils import *
```

should work.

Alternatively, if you don't want to turn `libraries` into a package you should add its path to `sys.path` and import `controller_utils`:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('libraries/')
from controller_utils import *
```

---

Note that the error is due to the fact that python2 requires the existence of `__init__.py` to import from packages while python3.3+ provides [namespace packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages) (see [PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)). That's why the import doesn't fail in python3.4.

If you want your code to work in both python2 and python3 in the same way you should always add `__init__.py` file to packages *and* use `from __future__ import absolute_import` in your files.

Comment: For Python 3 , its called `namespace package` . Details at - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/ or https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages or http://stackoverflow.com/a/32317916/795990

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes, I was just looking into that now.

Answer (score 1):

See [PEP 0404](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/#imports).

> In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer available - only absolute imports and explicit relative imports are supported. In addition, star imports (e.g. from x import *) are only permitted in module level code.

If `libraries` was in the same directory this would have happened to avoid clashes with packages installed at the system level. It would have been an implicit relative import.

You should be able to *navigate* to the correct location of the module using `..`, like:

```
from ..libraries.controller_utils import *
# or, depending of you directory structure
# put as many dots as directories you need to get out of
from ....common.libraries.controller_utils import *
```

But your case seems to be related to the *star import*. In Python 3 you can only use star imports (`from x import *`) at the top level of the file, i.e. not inside a function or class definition.

Comment: This is only valid for intra-package references, That is when the script having the issue is being imported by another script. That is not the case wit the OP , OP is directly launching python terminal and trying to import. In that case doing `..` would not work . It would complain that relative import went outside scope (or something similar)

Comment: @anand You're right. I'll leave my answer anyway since it could help someone else that gets here by searching for the same question.